Cannot connect to websocket server built with System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener from Postman
I am testing a simple websocket server with the following code in a Console application with .Net8. Can anyone please help to check what could be wrong? Thank you
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);

server.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Server has started on 127.0.0.1:8080.{0}Waiting for a connection…", Environment.NewLine);

TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

Console.WriteLine("A client connected.");

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

while (true)
{
    while (!stream.DataAvailable) ;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[client.Available];

    stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes));
}

However, when I try to connect to the server with Postman, I keep getting connecting state and cannot send message as follow

I tried to debug with console but there is nothing in it

Here is what I can see from the websocket server console

